# Memory leak with Couchbase Python SDK 3.2.2 (or 3.2.3) and how to disable tracing

Tags: python, memory-leaks, couchbase

I'm trying to migrate from Couchbase 2.5.12 into 3.2.2 (or 3.2.3) but I'm getting a mem leak. I faced this same [Problem](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/memory-leak-with-python-couchbase-2-5-0/21055/7) with 2.5.12 and I was able to sort that problem by disabling tracing in the connection string like this: `couchbase://localhost:8091?operation_timeout=15&bootstrap_on=http&detailed_errcodes=1&enable_tracing=false`.

When moved to Python SDK 3.2.2 I noticed that I have the same (mem leak) problem, so I tried to disable tracing by:

- Using same conn string (with enable_tracing=false) without luck, mem leak still persists
- Pass a ClusterTracingOptions instance to Cluster init with all fields set to None:

```py
    tracing_opts = ClusterTracingOptions(
        **dict(
            tracing_threshold_kv=None,
            tracing_threshold_view=None,
            tracing_threshold_query=None,
            tracing_threshold_search=None,
            tracing_threshold_analytics=None,
            tracing_threshold_queue_size=None,
            tracing_threshold_queue_flush_interval=None,
            tracing_orphaned_queue_size=None,
            tracing_orphaned_queue_flush_interval=None,
        )
    )
    clu = Cluster(
        COUCH_HOST,
        ClusterOptions(
            PasswordAuthenticator(COUCH_USER, COUCH_PASS),
        ),
        tracing_options=tracing_opts
    )
```

- Pass a Tracer (dummy obj) to Cluster init as:

```py
from couchbase.otel_tracing import CouchbaseOtelTracer
from opentelemetry import trace
...

    tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
    clu = Cluster(
        COUCH_HOST,
        ClusterOptions(
            PasswordAuthenticator(COUCH_USER, COUCH_PASS),
        ),
        tracer=CouchbaseOtelTracer(otel_tracer=tracer)
    )
```

- Used `tracing_opts` and `tracer` ^ toguether on Cluster init.

Any ideas on how can I disable tracing? or avoid the memory leak?

Here is a complete example of the fn that I'm executing:

```py
def multi_proc_insert(a_id, f_path):
    tracing_opts = ClusterTracingOptions(
        **dict(
            tracing_threshold_kv=None,
            tracing_threshold_view=None,
            tracing_threshold_query=None,
            tracing_threshold_search=None,
            tracing_threshold_analytics=None,
            tracing_threshold_queue_size=None,
            tracing_threshold_queue_flush_interval=None,
            tracing_orphaned_queue_size=None,
            tracing_orphaned_queue_flush_interval=None,
        )
    )
    tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
    clu = Cluster(
        COUCH_HOST,
        ClusterOptions(
            PasswordAuthenticator(COUCH_USER, COUCH_PASS),
        ),
        tracing_options=tracing_opts,
        tracer=CouchbaseOtelTracer(otel_tracer=tracer),
    )
    cbu = clu.bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
    collection = cbu.default_collection()
    lines = mapcount(f_path)
    logger.info(f"Start to process {f_path}\t lines: {lines}")
    inserted = 0

    t1 = time.time()
    with open(f_path, "r") as fp:
        while True:
            e_hash = fp.readline()
            if not e_hash:
                logger.info(f"e_hash not found (EOF)")
                break
            key = DOC_TYPE + e_hash.strip()
            try:
                collection.mutate_in(key, [SD.array_addunique("", a_id)])
            except PathExistsException:
                logger.debug(f"a_id {a_id} already exists on doc {key}")
            except DocumentNotFoundException:
                collection.insert(key, [a_id])
            except Exception:
                logger.exception(
                    f"Error processing {f_path}, inserted rows: {inserted} remaining: {lines - inserted}"
                )
            inserted += 1
    t2 = time.time()
    logger.info(
        f"Finished with {f_path}\t lines: {lines} inserted: {inserted} remaining: {lines - inserted} in seconds {t2 - t1}"
    )
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

With python sdk version 3.2.4, KV multi operations memory leak problem is fixed.

Just upgrade sdk to version 3.2.4 with python3 -m pip install --upgrade couchbase